# How can I use in a sentence the phrase 'ordinary folk'?

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning, grammaticality, phrase-request, phrases

Im trying to fill the blank of this sentence:

***Those were the heady days when stockbrokers commanded salaries beyond [...]of ordinary folk.***

It seems like i have to fill it with a phrase of three words, but I cannot think of any. I've tried with 'expected' and 'the scope of expertise' but I need three words.

I don't really understand the meaning of 'ordinary folk'. If someone could explain how to use that phrase I think it would be very helpful

Comment: "beyond the ... of" might give you a head start. Ordinary folk are ordinary people, ie nobody special.

Comment: "beyond the **reach** of..."

Answer (score 1):

> Those were the heady days when stockbrokers commanded salaries beyond
> **those** of ordinary folk.

Ordinary folk = ordinary people (i.e. not stockbrokers).

Answer (score 0):

If you genuinely need a phrase of exactly three words the usual cliche is

> Those were the heady days when stockbrokers commanded salaries beyond *the wildest dreams* of ordinary folk